# How can I fake the date returned by java.time.LocalDate?

Tags: java

I need to be able to fake the system time when testing. The source I have makes use of java.time.LocalDate. Is there a way to make `LocalDate.now()` return a pre-set date?

Comment: Make a wrapper method for calls to `LocalDate.now` and let it return your values if you're in a test case.

Comment: There is an overload of LocalDate.now which accepts a Clock. Can you use that?

Comment: You really should be injecting a Clock rather than trying to fake the system time.

Comment: You can refer to the below link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65014036/11628537

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a few options you've:

1. Wrap the `LocalDate.now()` call in a non-static method of a class. Then you can mock that method to return your specific instance - This would not seem practical if you're directly calling `LocalDate.now()` method at many places in your code.
2. Use `LocalDate.now(Clock)` method, that is pretty test-friendly, as already suggested in comments - again you've to modify your application code.
3. Use [`Powermockito`](https://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.5/apidocs/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html), if you can. In that case, you've a pretty easy approach by mocking static methods using [`mockStatic(Class<?>)`](https://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.5/apidocs/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html#mockStatic(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class...)) method.

The 3rd approach can be implemented as:

```
@PrepareForTest({ LocalDate.class })
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class DateTest {
    @Test
    public void yourTest() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(LocalDate.class);
        when(LocalDate.now()).thenReturn(yourLocalDateObj);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may need to put your class into list of prepared ones: `@PrepareForTest({MyFooService.class, LocalDate.class})`

Comment: How do I mock this line of code to return 2020-02-27 LocalDate.now().plusDays(Long.parseLong("0")).toString() but when it come to that line it returns todays date

Comment: Hi there. I just have a question about the 3rd approach listed here. When I attempt to do this, I get a NoSuchMethodError for the call to LocalDate.now(). Any idea why this might happen. I used the exact code that is shown in this example using my own 'yourLocalDateObj' defined as ```LocalDate localDate = PowerMockito.mock(LocalDate.class); ```

Answer (score 2):

I would usually suggest using Mockito, but since the method is static, you can't really mock the object.

Why not have some "DateProvider" class grab the date for you

```
public class DateProvider{
   public LocalDate getNow(){
      return LocalDate.now();
   }
}
```

and use it thusly:

```
new DateProvider().getNow();
```

That would make it fairly easy to test with any LocalDate return value

Answer (score 1):

Can you dependency inject the time through the constructor / parameter of the code?

Otherwise you can wrap LocalDate.now() in a static class that lets you hard-code a value for testing.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying the code on this page but I noticed I should get the LocalDate instance first before to use PowerMockito as the 2 firstLines of the next code

```
@Test
public void testYearOptions() throws Exception{

    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2015,11,12);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(LocalDate.class);

    Mockito.when(LocalDate.now()).thenReturn(date);
    Map<String, String> semesterMap = Utilities.getYears(); //Your function where LocalDate is Uses

    assertNotNull(yearsMap.get("2015"));//your assertion

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of spaghetti code here: keep it simple!
Write a *convenience method* and change its body to meet your needs.

```
public static LocalDate getCurrentTime() {
    // You can comment right code to save it during debugging
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For testing:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DateTimeFactoryTest {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DateTimeFactoryTest.class);

  @MockBean
  DateTimeFactory dateTimeFactory;

  @Test
  public void test001() throws MissingMethodInvocationException {
    given(dateTimeFactory.getLocalDate()).willReturn(LocalDate.of(2017,4, 4));
    LocalDate ld = dateTimeFactory.getLocalDate();
  }
}
```

Comment: How do I mock this line of code to return 2020-02-27 LocalDate.now().plusDays(Long.parseLong("0")).toString() but when it come to that line it returns todays date