# How to Mock only LocalDate.now() using PowerMock

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, java-time

I want to mock only the `now()` of `LocalDate` using PowerMock. It seems that it's ignoring the `thenReturn` value:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :2008
Actual   :2017
```

Test setup:

```
@PrepareForTest(LocalDate.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class UserTest {

    @Test
    public void nowShouldReturnSameYear() throws Exception {
        LocalDate expected = LocalDate.parse("2008-04-04");

        PowerMockito.spy(LocalDate.class);
        when(LocalDate.now()).thenReturn(expected);

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        assertEquals(expected.getYear(), foo.getRightNow().getYear());
    }
```

Foo.java

```
public LocalDate getRightNow(){
        final LocalDate rightNow = LocalDate.now();
        return rightNow;
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

You should `PrepareForTest` the `Foo` class:

```
@PrepareForTest(Foo.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class ...
```

I'm not sure how `spy` behaves for static methods, so I prefer to use `mockStatic`:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(LocalDate.class);
when(LocalDate.now())....
```

---

To make the code more testable and don't depend on mocking static methods, you could also refactor your code to use a `java.time.Clock`:

```
public class Foo {

    private Clock clock;

    public Foo() {
        // use the system's default clock
        this(Clock.systemDefaultZone());
    }

    public Foo(Clock clock) {
        // use a custom clock
        this.clock = clock;
    }

    public LocalDate getRightNow() {
        final LocalDate rightNow = LocalDate.now(this.clock);
        return rightNow;
    }
}
```

If you don't specify a `Clock`, it'll use the system's default (exactly what the `now()` method does when called without parameters).

Then, in your test, you create a `Clock` that always return the same date and pass it to the `Foo` class. In this case, you won't need all the PowerMockito stuff:

```
public class UserTest {

    @Test
    public void nowShouldReturnSameYear() throws Exception {
        LocalDate parse = LocalDate.parse("2008-04-04");
        // create a fixed clock (it always return the same date, using the system's default timezone)
        ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
        Clock clock = Clock.fixed(parse.atStartOfDay(zone).toInstant(), zone);

        Foo foo = new Foo(clock);
        assertEquals(parse.getYear(), foo.getRightNow().getYear());
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite get the idea of the more testable example where `java.time.Clock` is used. The constructor that does not take a clock argument is not covered in any test.

Comment: Check this one for a more clear answer for using `Clock` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792000/how-can-i-mock-java-time-localdate-now