# NullPointerException while PowerMocking LocalDate now

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, powermockito, localdate

I have the below code where I'm trying to insert a different for LocalDate.now using Powermockito.
My Source class is a util method which has only static methods and derives some default values based on the current date & I want to test this code for multiple date values.

I get the below exception, I see various articles stating that this should be working fine, Not sure if I'm doing something wrong here.

```
@PrepareForTest(LocalDate.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestClass {

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(LocalDate.class);
    }
    
    public void testMethod(){
        // Test Code goes here!
    }
    
}
```

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException

    at org.powermock.core.ClassReplicaCreator.createClassReplica(ClassReplicaCreator.java:65)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.getMockType(DefaultMockCreator.java:95)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.doCreateMock(DefaultMockCreator.java:57)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMock(DefaultMockCreator.java:53)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.mock(DefaultMockCreator.java:40)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic(PowerMockito.java:62)
    at com.test.TestClass.setUp(TestClass.java:26)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBefores(MethodRoadie.java:133)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:117)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions.setAccessible(SecurityActions.java:103)
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass3(DefineClassHelper.java:151)
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass2(DefineClassHelper.java:134)
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass(DefineClassHelper.java:95)
    at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1143)
    at javassist.CtClass.toClass(CtClass.java:1316)
    at org.powermock.core.ClassReplicaCreator.createClassReplica(ClassReplicaCreator.java:63)
    ... 35 more
```

Comment: Can you share the full stacktrace you are getting?

Comment: @Akortex, I have updated the description now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I mock java.time.LocalDate.now()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792000/how-can-i-mock-java-time-localdate-now)

Comment: @JayeshMulwani check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591919/how-to-mock-only-localdate-now-using-powermock

Comment: @AsadShakeel, Thanks for your response, I do understand that there are work arounds available for this however this is one of the solutions pointed out by the link shared by you. I would like to understand what's going wrong here.

Comment: @JayeshMulwani are you using the `Clock` to mock the date?

Comment: @AsadShakeel, No, I am trying to achieve this using just LocalDate.now() with PowerMockito.

Comment: Try using `Clock` in test class when returning the required date https://newbedev.com/how-can-i-mock-java-time-localdate-now

Comment: @AsadShakeel, As mentioned before, I know other ways to fix this anyways, I want to know what's going wrong with the current approach.