# How to test a code that invokes Instant.now() with JUnit 5?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, junit5

I have a code that looks somehow like this:

```
MyObject getMyObject() {
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    return myService.doSomething(now);
}
```

I know that PowerMock is not supported in JUnit 5, but I am wondering maybe there is a solution at least for standard API like dates.

Right now I am mocking the `Instant` instance with `Mockito.any()` which is incorrect as my test won't fail if I pass a wrong `Instant`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32792000/829571

Answer (score 4):

You can move the creation of current Instant to a package level method:

```
MyObject getMyObject() {
    Instant now = getCurrentInstance();
    return myService.doSomething(now);
}

Instant getCurrentInstant(){
  Instant.now();
}
```

Then in your test you can spy on the SUT and mock the `getCurrentInstant` method:

```
Sut sut = spy(new Sut());
doReturn(testInstance).when(sut).getCurrentInstant();

sut.getMyObject();
```

Here is an article I wrote on [Mockito Spying](https://www.sourceartists.com/blog/unit-testing/spying-with-mockito/13) if you need a further read.

Comment: I am not quite sure how it solves my problem. If I extract the `Instant.now()` to a new method I solve the problem with the original method. But now I have to test `getCurrentInstant()` method and I run into the same problem.

Comment: Why you need to test something which does not have logic and is not a public method?

Comment: It does have a logic, why do you think that returning current date is not a logic? One can easily break the method and no tests will fail.

Comment: you should not use when.then on spies.. as you invoke real method in the process

Comment: Logic to me is a conditional statement, loop, change of object state, exception being thrown.. but what we extracted here is literally a sort of getter. Besides you cannot test reliably a current date retrieval. You have to rely on it working and having it wrapped with a meaninngful name. Another thing why would want to test that java native method works?