# Mockito 3.6: Using mockStatic in @Before or @BeforeClass with JUnit4

Tags: java, java-8, mockito, mockstatic

Mockito 3.6 supports mocking static methods under a `try-with-resources` block as explained [here](https://wttech.blog/blog/2020/mocking-static-methods-made-possible-in-mockito-3.4.0/).

Can someone let me know if static methods are mocked using Powermock in `@Before` or `@BeforeClass` can `Mockito.mockStatic` be used to replace them without an entire rewrite of the test class?

Comment: Like @John said, this method works fine. My experience has been that the mock ***has*** to be closed in the After/AfterEach block, though. Otherwise you get a 'mock in use' error when the next test method is invoked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you might need to do a little bit of refactoring. You can create mocks of static methods by creating a MockedStatic variable at class level and use that in your tests and also sometimes it needs to be closed in the @After block, something like

```
MockedStatic<StaticClass> mockedStaticClass;
@Before
public void setUp()
{
  mockedStaticClass = Mockito.mockStatic(StaticClass.class);
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception
{
  mockedStaticClass.close();
}

@Test
public void yourTest()
{
  //make use of mockedStatic variable you created earlier
}
```

Comment: Nice one thanks. May be in variable declaration we could skip the type if we have multiple test cases with different static classes like MockedStatic mockedStaticClass;