# How to Mock a ZonedDateTime with Mockito and Junit

Tags: java, mockito

I need to mock a `ZonedDateTime.ofInstant()` method. I know there are many suggestions in SO but for my specific problem, till now I did not get any simple way out.

Here is my code :

```
public ZonedDateTime myMethodToTest(){

    MyClass myClass;
    myClass = fetchSomethingFromDB();
    try{
        final ZoneId systemDefault = ZoneId.systemDefault();
        return ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(myClass.getEndDt().toInstant(), systemDefault);
    } catch(DateTimeException dte) {
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

Here is my incomplete Test method :

```
 @Mock
 MyClass mockMyClass;

 @Test(expected = DateTimeException.class)
 public void testmyMethodToTest_Exception() {
    String error = "Error while parsing the effective end date";
    doThrow(new DateTimeException(error)).when(--need to mock here---);
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = mockMyClass.myMethodTotest();
}
```

I want to mock the `ZonedDateTime.ofInstant()` method to throw a DateTimeException while parsing for the negative scenario. How I can do that.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "while parsing for the negative scenario"? When do you expect `ofInstant` to fail? And is there any reason you have to do this with mocking rather than injecting the time zone (which will help with all kinds of testing) and just using a suitable zone/instant combination? (In other words, I'd say that the first sentence of this question is wrong - you need to test your code, but that's not the same as needing to mock ofInstant.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `Mockito` for this because `ZonedDateTime` is a final class and `ofInstant` is a *static* method, but you can use the `PowerMock` library to enhance `Mockito` capabilities:

```
final String error = "Error while parsing the effective end date";
// Enable static mocking for all methods of a class
mockStatic(ZonedDateTime.class);
PowerMockito.doThrow(new DateTimeException(error).when(ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Mockito.anyObject(), Mockito.anyObject()));
```

Comment: ZonedDateTime is a final Class. It cannot be mocked in this way.

Comment: You're right, then the only solution is to use something like PowerMockito

Comment: @EduardoYáñezParareda `mockStatic` does not return a mocked object. The stubbing is to be done on the class, once it is mocked via `mockStatic()`.

Comment: Yes, I made mistakes when adapting to PowerMock, now it should be ok.

Comment: Current version of Mockito supports mocking statics too.

Comment: @EduardoYáñezParareda The parentheses on the last line are still off, fyi.

Answer (score 11):

As of now (18/03/2022) Mockito supports mocking static methods. You can do

```
@Test
public void testDate() {
    String instantExpected = "2022-03-14T09:33:52Z";
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(instantExpected);

    try (MockedStatic<ZonedDateTime> mockedLocalDateTime = Mockito.mockStatic(ZonedDateTime.class)) {
        mockedLocalDateTime.when(ZonedDateTime::now).thenReturn(zonedDateTime);

        assertThat(yourService.getCurrentDate()).isEqualTo(zonedDateTime);
    }
}
```

Please note that you need to use `mockito-inline` dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 01/14/2023 with "mockito-core" 5.0.0, we don't need to add "mockito-inline" dependency anymore to mock ZonedDateTime with Mockito.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Then, use it as:

```
    @Test
    void test() {
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2024-01-01T00:00:00.000000+03:00[Europe/Istanbul]");
    try (MockedStatic<ZonedDateTime> mockedStatic = mockStatic(ZonedDateTime.class)) {
        mockedStatic.when(() -> ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Istanbul"))).thenReturn(zonedDateTime);
        System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Istanbul")));
    }
}
```